# MongoDB/Javascript: ReferenceError: lastname is not defined

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In my database collection i have this pair `{lastname: "Smith", name: "John"}` and i want to find it using this code:

```
db.collection.find({'$where':'function(){return lastname=="Smith";}'})
```

This code should return something like true or 1 but instead it returns an error:

```
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "ReferenceError: lastname is not defined :\n_funcs1@:1:22\n",
        "code" : 139
```

As it is javascript inside mongodb query maybe the problem is that javascript isn't interpreted... any idea ?

Cheers

Comment: Why not `db.collection.find({lastname: "Smith"})`? Using `$where` is computationally expensive and normally considered to be used as a last resort option due to the way it executes and resulting performance.

Comment: Because, there is a challenge i want to validate on a website (root - me . org), and i'm compelled to use this structure

Comment: You need to reference the document in the JavaScript expression or function using either `this` or `obj`.

Comment: Thanks you  !! it works !!